# How do I convert Oracle's byte representation of NUMERIC into a java BigDecimal?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

When grabing a NUMERIC type from Oracle, I would like to invoke

`ResultSet.getBytes()` instead of `ResultSet.getBigDecimal()`

At some later point I would like to convert the byte array to BigDecimal.

Does anyone know a way to do this?  I looked at the Oracle documentation and only has a small paragraph about its "Internal Numeric Format".

Comment: What does `getBytes` return for known values?

Comment: My understanding is that it's stored as a base 100 floating point value.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's wrong using `getBigDecimal()`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [link](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/number_format.html). Note that's not part of Oracle's official documentation, just some guy who reverse engineered it.